# Binary classification problem

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, statistics, discrete-mathematics, machine-learning

This problem is in the context of binary classification. Let $f_\omega (t) = \mathcal I[\sin (\omega t) \geq 0]$, and $\mathcal F = \{ f_{\omega} : \omega \in R\}$, $t\in\mathbb R$. For any given $m = 1, 2, 3, \dots$ find a set of $m$ points $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m$ on $\mathbb R$ such that for every point $x_i$ and an arbitrary "label" $y_i \in \{ 0, 1\}$ associated to it, we can always find $g\in\mathcal F$ such that $g(x_i) =  y_i$ for every $i \in [1, m]$. I have to use the following fact. For any $z\in (0, 1)$, $\mathcal I[\sin(2^i \pi z) \geq 0] = 1 - z_i$, where $z_i$ is the $i$-th "bit" of the base-2 representation of $z$, e.g., $z = \sum^{\infty}_{i=1}z_i 2^{-i}$.

I'm stuck at how to choose the $m$ points. My initial guess was to set $x_i = 2^{-i}$, but I don't see how can I use the fact I have to use since the labels should be arbitrary. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $p_n(t)=f_{2^n\pi}(t)=[\sin2^n\pi t\ge0]$ and let $x_1=\frac23=0.\overline{10}_2$. Then the given fact implies that $p_k(x_1)$ is the last bit of $k$. Similarly we choose $x_2=0.\overline{1100}_2=\frac45,x_3=0.\overline{11110000}_2=\frac{16}{17}$, etc. – in general
$$x_n=0.\overline{\underbrace{1\dots1}_{2^{n-1}}\underbrace{0\dots0}_{2^{n-1}}}_2=1-\frac1{2^{2^{n-1}}+1}$$
and $p_k(x_n)$ is the $n$th least significant bit of $k$ for nonnegative integer $k$.

With these $x_i$, if we are given arbitrary labels $y_i$ forming the integer $z=(y_m\dots y_1)_2$, we simply choose $g=p_z=f_{2^z\pi}$. For $1\le i\le m$, $g(x_i)=p_z(x_i)$ will give the $i$-th least significant bit of $z$, i.e. $y_i$.